# How to 'only if a page' to a conditional statement in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to only turn on the content block if $option_header doesn't equal yes, and the post type is a page.

I'm a total noob with minimal php skills.

This is what I thought should work, but it doesn't.

```php
if(($option_header != 'yes' && $post_type == 'page'
                ) ){?>
```

Display the header if not yes, and a page (not a post)

Comment: Check out the WordPress docs [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress comes with some very useful [in-built conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to check "where" you are. One of them is `is_page()`, which checks to true "only if a page" as you need. You can use it as:

```
if($option_header !== 'yes' && is_page() ){?>
```